# php sendmail headers not working correctly

Tags: php, email

I have the following headers in my Mailer class

```
// domain is equal to current domain with capital letters if any
$from = domain;
$replyto = 'noreply@'.strtolower(domain);

$headers = "From: $from\r\nReply-To: ".$replyto;
$headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\nContent-Type: text/html; charset=\"utf-8\"\r\n";
```

But for some reason when I send an email in my mailbox I receive an e-mail from myusername@myhost.com which is terrible. How can I have just my site name as the sender?

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you sometimes use `\r\n` between two headers and sometimes just `\n`?

Comment: Lots of different settings can influence the mail headers. The most trivial is the mail server's config. You can try to send mails with the mail unix cli to verify what happens with the headers. (It is only the first step of debugging.) Or maybe with telnet in localhost. Otherwise using phpmailer can be a good idea.

But probably your servers MTA forces the unwanted mail address.

Comment: Do you use `mail()` function from php? building headers manually can be a pain, I migrated to http://pear.php.net/manual/de/package.mail.mail.php which is vastly easier to work with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to parse names and email-addresses correctly, you should provide them in the following format:

```
'From: Name <email@domain.tld>'
```

So that would be something like

```
'From: Marty McVry <marty.mcvry@mydomain.com>'
```

Using your example:

```
$headers = "From: $from <$replyto>\r\nReply-To: ".$replyto;
```

Just a reminder: I hope that you don't have to use `$domain` instead of `domain`... Would be a silly typo otherwise. :-)

Comment: Awesome stuff! Thank you mr. McVry.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using this code:

```
<?php
$to      = 'nobody@example.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

For more information, read about the [mail function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)